# Laravel Sail (docker), nginx reverse proxy - Html renders localhost:8002 instead of site.xyz

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, laravel-sail

I started testing the new Laravel Sail docker-compose environment with an nginx reverse proxy so I can access my website from a real tld while developing on my local machine.

My setup is:
OS - Ubuntu Desktop 20 with nginx and docker installed.

Nginx site-enabled on the host machine:

```
server {

        server_name mysite.xyz;

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mysite.xyz.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/mysite.xyz.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
        }

}
```

Also I have **127.0.0.1        mysite.xyz** in my host machine /etc/hosts file

And my docker-compose:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '8002:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sailredis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
    sailredis:
        driver: local
```

Site is loading fine when I access mysite.xyz from my host machine.

The issue I'm having is that on the register page that I ca see from my host machine by accessing the register page (https://mysite.xyz/register) the form action is: **http://localhost:8002/register**

The piece of code that generates the above url is `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">`

This is a problem because I don't access the site from localhost:XXXX but instead from mysite.xyz which goes through the nginx reverse proxy and eventually ends up pointing to http://localhost:8002/register
**

What I checked:

In my Laravel .env file, the APP_URL is mysite.xyz
if I ssh into the the sail container and start artisan tinker and then run `route('register')` it outputs **https://mysite.xyz/**  so clearly, the laravel app inside the container seems to be behaving correctly.

The funny thing is that when it renders the html response, it renders the register route as **http://localhost:8002/register**

I tried searching the entire project for localhost:8002 and I can find it in /storage/framework/sessions/asdofhsdfasf8as7dgf8as7ogdf8asgd7
that bit of text says: {s:3:"url";s:27:"http://localhost:8002/login";}

So it seems that the session thinks it's localhost:8002 but tinker thinks it's mysite.xyz

I'm also a docker noob so who knows what I'm missing. I'm lost :)

Comment: what is the `APP_URL` value in your `.env` file?

Comment: it's https://mysite.xyz

Comment: `php artisan config:cache && php artisan route:cache && php artisan view:cache`? Can you try this

Comment: @onlineThomas no luck with the commands above. Inside the docker container, the app SEEMS to know what its name is. From the docker container, if I curl http://mysite.xyz/login, I get the output html which contains https://mysite.xyz urls - which is correct. But when I access the site from my host computer, via the reverse proxy, I see localhost:8002

Comment: I have this problem when running Laravel Sail in a Github Codespace

Answer (score 5):

The "problem" lies within your nginx configuration, not your code:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
```

Laravel uses APP_URL in CLI (console) or whenever you use `config('app.url')` or `env('APP_URL')` in your code. For all other operations (such as URL constructing via the route helper) Laravel fetches the URL from the request:

[URL Generation, Laravel 8.x Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#generating-urls)

> The url helper may be used to generate arbitrary URLs for your application. The generated URL will automatically use the scheme (HTTP or HTTPS) and host **from the current request** being handled by the application.

What you need to do is to pass the correct URL and port in your nginx configuration, by adding:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

For additional information on the topic, you may want to have a look at this article: [Setting up an Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://linuxize.com/post/nginx-reverse-proxy/)